# OQL query to find Spring ApplicationContext holding specific bean

Tags: spring, heap-memory, oql

I use Spring Boot and have problem with beans instantiating (they created twice).

How can I find reference to ApplicationContext from bean reference in OQL query? In other word find out holding Context for given bean.

**PS**
Basic troubleshooting query in VisualVM:

```
heap.objects("org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext")
heap.objects("org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find beans instances by bean name per `ApplicationContext`::

```
map(heap.objects("org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext"), function(it) {
  var fact = it.beanFactory;
  var tbl = fact.singletonObjects.table;
  var beans = map(filter(tbl, "it && /Step$/.test(it.key)"), "{key: it.key, val: it.val}");
  return {ctx: it, beans: beans};
})
```

Find beans instances by class name per `ApplicationContext`::

```
map(heap.objects("org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext"), function(it) {
  var fact = it.beanFactory;
  var tbl = fact.singletonObjects.table;
  var beans = map(filter(tbl, "it && /^com.bigbrother/.test(classof(it.val).name)"), "{key: it.key, val: it.val}");
  return {ctx: it, beans: beans};
})
```

If Spring change underlying implementation these queries should be adjusted. Look for fields:

```
heap.objects("org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext")
```